# Long Pooling for HTTP stream endpoint

Tags: apex, webservices, web

I'm looking to try setup server side long pooling connection to a http POST */steam endpoint.

- I originally looked at an LWC making a handshake using the cometD, but this will only keep the connection alive for as long as the user is active on the site.

How can I setup a connection to get live updates from my Oanda endpoint?

- Essentially I currently use salesforce to daily log my trades, but I want to do this through the day to get live transactions to run for 5 days a week.
- I have also seen some items on a infinite queueable call, is this best practise or should I use another technique?

Any suggestions is help, thanks :)

Comment: Take a look at https://architect.salesforce.com/decision-guides/data-integration and https://architect.salesforce.com/decision-guides/event-driven

Comment: As mentioned in your question, `I originally looked at an LWC making a handshake using the cometD, but this will only keep the connection alive for as long as the user is active on the site.`. why do you want to poll when no user is active. Why won't Platform event, or any streaming api work here?

Comment: I want it to run 5 days a week, and pickup all transactions made on my account. With streaming API can i setup a connection to the desired URL without any additonal development from Oanda? I want to receive live updates from Oanda, not send live updates when data in SF is updated

Comment: I have also been looing into mulesoft to bridge the gap. Is this a viable solution?

Comment: @CalDe How about scheduling an outbound call from Apex to run, let's say, every 5 minutes and fetch the data from the endpoint?